# Emotion CSS prop doesn't work in Storybook v7

Tags: reactjs, storybook, emotion

After an upgrade of the storybook from v.6.5 to v7 the Emotion stopped working.
After many unsuccessful tries, I have no idea where the problem could be.

`button.stories.tsx`:

```
import {
  Meta, StoryObj,
} from '@storybook/react';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';

const meta: Meta<typeof ButtonComponent> = {
  component: ButtonComponent,
  title: 'ButtonComponent',
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof ButtonComponent>;

export const Primary: Story = {
  render: (args) => <ButtonComponent {...args} />,
};
```

When inspecting the rendered component it has a **css** attribute with this value:

"You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't
supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to
emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop)."

Project structure:

```
app
 |-resources
 |     |-js
 |        |-.storybook
 |        |       |-main.js     
 |        |       |-preview.js
 |        |
 |        |-src
 |           |-*whole application here*
 |
 |-.babelrc
 |-package.json
 |-webpack.js
```

`package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "7.0.10",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "7.0.10",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^1.0.7",
    "@storybook/addon-toolbars": "7.0.10",
    "@storybook/preset-typescript": "3.0.0",
    "@storybook/react": "7.0.10",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.0.10",
    "storybook": "^7.0.10",
    ...
}
```

`.storybook/main.js`

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx)?'],
  features: {
    emotionAlias: false,
  },
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-toolbars',
    {
      name: '@storybook/preset-typescript',
      options: {
        tsLoaderOptions: {
          configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')
        }
      }
    },
    '@storybook/addon-controls',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-storysource',
      options: {
        rule: {
          test: /\.story\.tsx?$/,
          include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')]
        },
        loaderOptions: {
          prettierConfig: {
            printWidth: 80,
            singleQuote: false
          },
          parser: 'typescript'
        }
      }
    },
    '@storybook/addon-styling'
  ],
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    config.resolve.modules = [...(config.resolve.modules || []), path.resolve(__dirname, "../src")];
    config.plugins.forEach(plugin => {
      if ('ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin' === plugin.constructor.name) {
        plugin.tsconfig = path.resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.json');
      }
    });
    return config;
  },
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
    options: {}
  },
};
```

`.storybook/preview.js`

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { darkTheme } from '../src/_shared/themes/dark.theme';

const preview = {
    decorators: [
      (Story) => (
        <div>
          <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
              <Story />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </div>
      ),
    ],
};
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-react", { "runtime": "automatic", "importSource": "@emotion/react" }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "corejs": "3.22"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@emotion",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "dynamic-import-node",
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Could there be any problem with my configuration that I miss?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    // Fix for css prop
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
          options: {
            plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).